# FTP text-editor that allows Folder bookmarks?

Tags: windows-7, text-editor, ftp, bookmark

Do you have a recommendation for an FTP software which includes a text editor, and in addition to that allows Folder bookmarks? (bookmarks that will lead you to a certain path at the home directory, instead of navigating manually to it time and again).

Comment: Which OS? Price? Please also clarify what exactly it us you want - an FTP client with can also be used as a text-editor? What do you mean my 'folder bookmarks'?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning my OS. I use Windows 7. I am looking for a Free software only. I want a program like Notepad++ that indeed uses both as a Text editor and an FTP client. The problem for me with Notepad++ is that id don't have the option to make Folder bookmarks, i.e Folder shortcuts - Bookmarks that will lead you to and exact path\folder.

Comment: Your question is still unclear (to me). You want to edit *on the server* and include bookmarks. Does that mean that you want to edit *HTML files*? How would you want those bookmarks to be inserted - does the user pick the files from the local server directory structure and should the software translate this to the public HREF? And [edit] your answers into your question, please.

Comment: I want to edit many types of files (mainly CSS)... All my aim is NOT to navigate manually to the relevant files each time... That's why i need this (So called if you wish) Bookmarks, or path shortcuts.

If you know a program which is an FTP client (That allow such bookmarks), and also includes a text editor, I'll be glad to know it's name.

Comment: What other features do you require from such text editor (except from the FTP features)? Do you e.g. need syntax highlighting, code-folding, spell-checking, auto-complete, …?